# WPF: how to pass 2 text properties from 2 TextBoxes into my Button command

Tags: wpf, xaml, icommand

So i have 2 `TextBox` and button with simple command:

```xml
    <Button ToolTip="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
```

And i want to pass to this command the 2 `Text` properties from my 2 `TexBox`.

In case i want to pass only 1 `Text` property i used this `command`:

```xml
CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=yourTextBox}"
```

Any chance to do that without `Converter` ?

Comment: How do you want do aggregate them? Concatenate two strings or something different?

Comment: I prefer without Concatenate unless this is the only option

Comment: You can use multivalue converter for example, and pass two strings into it, but the result will be a single string with text (or other object). You have to consider for yourself, which logic do you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a converter for multiple values by implementing [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.8) interface:

```cs
public class MultiTextConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //logic to aggregate two texts from object[] values into one object
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new[] { Binding.DoNothing };
    }
}
```

Then use it in xaml. Declare the converter instance in `Window` or `App` resources

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>                    
    <MultiTextConverter x:Key="multiTextConverter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And use in button `CommandParameter` binding

```xml
<Button ToolTip="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}">
   <Button.CommandParameter>
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiTextConverter}">
           <Binding ElementName="yourTextBox1" Path="Text"/>
           <Binding ElementName="yourTextBox2" Path="Text"/>
       </MultiBinding>
   </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this would be to just bind the Text property of the two text boxes to strings in the View Model, and handle those strings inside the Execute() method of your ICommand.

View:

```
<TextBox x:Name="firstTextBox" Text="{Binding FirstText}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="secondTextBox" Text="{Binding SecondText}"/>
```

View Model:

```
public string FirstText { get; set; } //Also invoke PropertyChanged event if necessary
public string SecondText { get; set; }
```